# how to pass both function pointers and lambda's using one interface

Tags: c++11, lambda

I am trying to use function pointers and lambdas together using one interface. I decided to use `std::function`, but I quickly found out that it cannot deal with overloaded functions by itself.

Example:

```
void foobar(double i_double ){std::cout << "double argument" << i_double << std::endl;}
void foobar(){std::cout << "no argument" << std::endl;}
void foobar(int){std::cout << "int argument" << std::endl;}

std::function<void(double)> func = static_cast<void(*)(double)>(&foobar);
```

This code only compiles by using a `static_cast`. Since at our company we have quite a lot of overloaded functions this is too much of a hassle. For now I decided to implement two interfaces: One for `std::function` objects and another one for function pointers, although I would really like to just wrap the function pointers in a `std::function` object as well (without additional code on the calling side).

Any "nice" solution to this problem?

edit:
The way I will be using it is part of a large framework, but boils down to the code below. I hope the following code below makes the use case clear.

```
namespace
{
    bool IsAllowed(string) {...}
    bool IsAllowed(int) {...}
}

CIteratorFilter<String>( listofstrings, IsAllowed );

CSomeObject object;
CIteratorFilter<String>( listofstrings, 
    [&object](String i_string ) { return object.IsAllowed( i_string ); } 
);
```

Currently this CIteratorFilter needs to implement both the function pointer and `std::function` interface, which is not really nice in my opinion.

Comment: show us how you intend to use this. It looks like a XY problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See... an XY problem.

This or anything similar is not needed:

```
std::function<void(double)> func = static_cast<void(*)(double)>(&foobar);
```

You need to use templates:

```
template <class Func>
CIteratorFilter<String>( listofstrings, Func func) {
  // call func whatever it may be function pointer, lambda, callable object:
  func(..whatever params...);
}
```

<sub>you can use perfect fowarding for `func` if you want</sub>

Comment: The CIteratorFilter is itself template, could i make it possible to template the constructor and forward the arguments to the base class constructor?

Comment: Your syntax in not actually valid c++ so I did my best guess as how your code would actually look. It is possible. Post actual code (very small but  compileable)

Comment: Hm i tried to do it, but the templated constructor on CIteratorFilter doesn't work for function pointers with overloaded methods again.. Same issue as before :(

Comment: for that use the solution provided by [Joachim Pileborg](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30529843/2805305) wrap it inside a lambda

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a non-capturing lambda with the correct argument and that calls the `foobar` function?

Like

```
std::function<void(double)> func = [](double d){ foobar(d); };
```

That's the nicest I can think of.

Comment: or even better: `auto func =`

Comment: I think i should mention that currently there already exists a large framework.. which means i would need to rewrite all that code using lamba's everywhere, which is ugly and should not be needed in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Use C++11 features with macro-magic.

```
#define FUNCTION(RETURN, NAME, ...) \
  std::function<RETURN (__VA_ARGS__)>(static_cast<RETURN(*)(__VA_ARGS__)>(&NAME))
```

Usage:

```
auto func1 = FUNCTION(void, foobar, double);
auto func2 = FUNCTION(void, foobar);
auto func3 = FUNCTION(void, foobar, int);
```

If you don't want to use variable argument then below is an alternate way of doing it:

```
#define FUNCTION(RETURN, NAME, PARAMETERS) \
  std::function<RETURN PARAMETERS>(static_cast<RETURN(*)PARAMETERS>(&NAME))
```

Usage:

```
auto func1 = FUNCTION(void, foobar, (double));
auto func2 = FUNCTION(void, foobar, ());
auto func3 = FUNCTION(void, foobar, (int));
```